# What's the best way to use Visual Studio 2010 and TFS with Xenapp

Tags: visual-studio-2010, citrix, xenapp

Management wants us to start using Visual Studio through Xenapp when we are working remotely.  I can't find any good documents about how teams are using this.  The biggest issue seems to be managing workspaces.  Most development can be done without a connection using TDD but getting the latest versions is a problem.  The Xenapp version of VS doesn't recognize the workspace on the local machine.  You can create a workspace to the virtual desktop but then you would need to develop in the virtual machine.  If you do map the the virtual environment to the local it gets all files again.  This is a problem as that alone can take up to an hour.

We have 4 Xenapp servers that are load balanced so you never know which one you will end up on.  If anyone is doing this I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I've never used XenApp.  Is the path that XenApp gives VS access to deterministic such that you could use the same path for your workspace when you are running VS normally?

Comment: It does not recognize that the files already exist at your normal path and gets every file again...  Also the build time becomes very slow because a virtual pc is trying build from files that are on your local pc so it is going over the internet constantly...

Comment: I'm not sure of a good solution in this case since you cannot use the same paths each time.

Comment: Buck, If our Tech Service department could map developers to a consistent box would you have a good solution?

Comment: If they map to the same box, then yes, you could then script changing the workspace for the user from being where it was to being where it needs to be.  That wouldn't be any different than setting up a new workspace though if the files are no longer on disk from the previous usage.